# Read and print numbers from a .dat file

Tags: c, file

I need to read and print the contents from a .dat file consisting of 3 columns of numbers.  When I input a 1, indicating file 1, the output is 3 columns of 0.00 and when they input a 2, indicating file 2, there is no output.

So far I have

```
int file, k = 0; 
float img_x, img_y, img_z, num_data = 0;  
FILE *img = NULL; 
printf("Enter file number:   "); 
scanf("%int", &file); 

if (file == 1)  
{   
    img = fopen("img1.dat", "r"); 
}   
else if (file == 2)  
{ 
    img = fopen("img2.dat", "r"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    printf("Error opening input file \n"); 
    return 0; 
} 
if (img == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Error opening input file \n"); 
    return 0; 
} 
fscanf(img, "%f", &num_data); 
for (k = 1; k <= num_data; k++) 
{ 
    fscanf(img, "%f %f %f \n", &img_x, &img_y, &img_z); 
    printf("%4.2f ", &img_x); 
    printf("%4.2f ", &img_y); 
    printf("%4.2f\n", &img_z);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read the man pages for `scanf` and `printf`. You aren't using them correctly, and the compiler should be generating warnings for the `printfs`.

Comment: and learn to use a debugger so you can step through the code

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  then fix the warnings.   Note: the correct format specifier for an integer input is NOT "%int" but rather either "%i" or more commonly "%d"

Comment: please, for readability/understandability by us humans, consistently indent the code.  do no use tabs for indenting as every word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces as that does not quickly eat up the available page width and is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.   indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   It is also a good practice to separate code blocks (like if, else, while, do...while, for) by a blank line

Comment: this printed output: "Error opening input file \n" does not tell the user what is wrong,   was it a invalid file number or did the open() statement fail and if the open statement failed, why did it fail.   Suggest, when a open statement fails use the function: `perror()` as it will print the enclosed text and the reason for the open failure.

Comment: It might be important to note that image files do not start with a float number.   they usually start with a two byte code that indicates the specific type of image in the file.

Comment: when calling the function scanf() or fscanf(), always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: these functions return a counter of the number of format specifiers that were successfully input/converted